# How do you generate typings for protobuf files for use with GRPC?

Tags: node.js, typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to use GRPC with TypeScript, and I am trying to make sure I have all the types set (rather than just adding my own mapping or using `any`.

I've gotten as far as with problems I am experiencing noted in the comments.

```js
import { Server, loadPackageDefinition } from "grpc";
import { loadSync } from "@grpc/proto-loader";

const packageDefinition = loadSync(__dirname + "/protos/artifact.proto");
const artifacts = loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).artifacts;

// what are the types here?
function SignedUrlPutObject(call, callback) {
}

const server = new Server();
// There's no ArtifactUpload defined in artifacts
server.addService(artifacts.ArtifactUpload.service, { SignedUrlPutObject })
```

Another approach I tried was to use `pbjs` and `pbts`.

```json
"protobuf": "pbjs -t static-module -w commonjs -o protos.js protos/artifact-upload.proto && pbts -o protos.d.ts protos.js",
```

This generated the typings file, but I can't get it to work with grpc.  Here's a github issue I found that may be related https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/1381

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's 3 main tools you can use:

1. [ts-protoc-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-protoc-gen)
2. [@grpc/proto-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/proto-loader)
3. [grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts)

I recommend using proto-loader:

```
npm i @grpc/proto-loader
```

You can then generate the types like so:

```
./node_modules/.bin/proto-loader-gen-types --longs=String --enums=String --defaults --oneofs --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js --outDir=proto/ proto/*.proto
```

Here's the proto file I use for this example:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package example_package;

message ServerMessage {
  string server_message = 1;
}

message ClientMessage {
  string client_message = 1;
}

service Example {
  rpc unaryCall(ClientMessage) returns (ServerMessage) {}
  rpc serverStreamingCall(ClientMessage) returns (stream ServerMessage) {}
  rpc clientStreamingCall(stream ClientMessage) returns (ServerMessage) {}
  rpc bidirectionalStreamingCall(stream ClientMessage) returns (stream ServerMessage) {}
}
```

Once the types are generated, you can consume them like so:

```
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
import { ProtoGrpcType } from './proto/example';
import { ClientMessage } from './proto/example_package/ClientMessage';
import { ExampleHandlers } from './proto/example_package/Example';
import { ServerMessage } from './proto/example_package/ServerMessage';

const host = '0.0.0.0:9090';

const exampleServer: ExampleHandlers = {
  unaryCall(
    call: grpc.ServerUnaryCall<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>,
    callback: grpc.sendUnaryData<ServerMessage>
  ) {
    if (call.request) {
      console.log(`(server) Got client message: ${call.request.clientMessage}`);
    }
    callback(null, {
      serverMessage: 'Message from server',
    });
  },

  serverStreamingCall(
    call: grpc.ServerWritableStream<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>
  ) {
    call.write({
      serverMessage: 'Message from server',
    });
  },

  clientStreamingCall(
    call: grpc.ServerReadableStream<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>
  ) {
    call.on('data', (clientMessage: ClientMessage) => {
      console.log(
        `(server) Got client message: ${clientMessage.clientMessage}`
      );
    });
  },

  bidirectionalStreamingCall(
    call: grpc.ServerDuplexStream<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>
  ) {
    call.write({
      serverMessage: 'Message from server',
    });
    call.on('data', (clientMessage: ClientMessage) => {
      console.log(
        `(server) Got client message: ${clientMessage.clientMessage}`
      );
    });
  },
};

function getServer(): grpc.Server {
  const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('./proto/example.proto');
  const proto = (grpc.loadPackageDefinition(
    packageDefinition
  ) as unknown) as ProtoGrpcType;
  const server = new grpc.Server();
  server.addService(proto.example_package.Example.service, exampleServer);
  return server;
}

if (require.main === module) {
  const server = getServer();
  server.bindAsync(
    host,
    grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
    (err: Error | null, port: number) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Server error: ${err.message}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Server bound on port: ${port}`);
        server.start();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**I've created various examples of how to use gRPC with TypeScript here: https://github.com/badsyntax/grpc-js-types**

Comment: The current example(also them on your github repo) are outdated. The example uses `client.unaryCall` but currently, what is being used is makeUnaryRequest. Could you provide us example to that please? Thanks!

Comment: @Simon Sola I've created an issue to update the examples https://github.com/badsyntax/grpc-js-typescript/issues/18

Comment: @SimonSoka There's nothing wrong with the example. The rpc methods are defined in the proto file, so your proto file probably has the definition for "makeUnaryRequest". I've updated the answer to include the proto file to prevent confusion.